# Proving the inverse of a continuous function is also continuous

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity, compactness, inverse

> Let $E, E'$ be metric spaces, $f: E\to E'$ a continuous function. Prove that if $E$ is compact and $f$ is bijective then $f^{-1}:E' \to E$ is continuous.

I know one way to prove it is by showing that if $S\subset E$ and $S$ is closed then $f(s)\subset E'$ is also closed where $s\in S$. Since $S$ is closed then $p_n \in S$ and $p_n \to p_0$ in $E$ then $p_o\in S$. Since $E$ is compact there is a convergent subsequence. How can I do this proof?

Comment: Use the concept of open or closed sets!

Comment: @UNM I did use that.

Comment: Note: metric spaces aren't even required. Hausdorff spaces are good enough.

Answer (score 24):

For proving it we use the if and only if condition that continuous function bring back closed sets to closed sets.

Let $F$ be a closed set in $E$.
Since $E$ is compact, $F$ is compact.
hence $f(F)$ is compact and hence closed.

Now $(f^{-1})^{-1}(F)=f(F)$ is closed.

Since the choice of $F$ was arbitrary, $(f^{-1})$ brings back closed sets to closed sets. hence $f^{-1}$ is continuous.

Answer (score 11):

We need to prove that $f(A)$ is closed for all closed set $A$ in compact space $K$.

Indeed, $\forall \{y_n \} \subset f(A)$, we assume that $y_n \to y$. We will show that $y \in f(A)$.

We have $f$ is continuous and A is a compact set, so $f(A)$ is also a compact set. By the definition of compact set, we obtain that $\forall \{ y_n\} \subset f(A)$, $\exists \{y_{n_k} \} \subset \{ y_n\}$: $y_{n_k}\to y_0 \in f(A)$. Since $y_n \to y$, $y_{n_k}\to y$. Thus $y=y_0\in f(A)$.

Comment: Almost four years after the [request](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541082/proving-the-inverse-of-a-continuous-function-is-also-continuous/541107#comment1153199_541107) by the OP, someone finally write down the proof using sequential criteria. Hope the OP sees this.

Answer (score 4):

All metric spaces are Hausdorff. Given a continuous bijection between a compact space and a Hausdorff space the map is a homeomorphism.

Proof:

We show that $f$ is a closed map. Let $K \subset E_1$ be closed then it is compact so $f(K)$ is compact and compact subsets of Hausdorff spaces are closed. Hence, we have that $f$ is a homeomorphism.

Answer (score -1):

**Theorem 1**:  A mapping f of a metric space X into a metric space Y is continuous on X if and only if $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in X for every open set V in Y.

**Theorem 2**: $f$ is a continuous mapping of a compact metric space X into a metric space Y. Then $f(X)$ is compact.

Based on Theorem 1, it is suffice to show that $f(V)$ is an open set in Y for every open set V in X.

Fix such a set V. $V^c$ is closed in X, hence compact.  Theorem 2 tells us $f(V^{c})$ is a compact subset of Y and so is closed in Y. Since Y is one-to-one and onto, $f(V)$ is the complement of $f(V^{c})$. Hence $f(V)$ is open.