# End points of different parametrizations of the same curve

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, parametrization

I was reading about parametrized curves.
The definition is in terms of a parametrized curve is in terms of the parametrization itself rather than the curve as a subset.

Precisely, A parametrized curve is a function $z(t)$ which maps a closed interval $[a, b] \subset \mathbb{R}$ to the complex plane. Let us assume that the function is bijective, differentiable with derivative not zero anywhere. Now if we have a different parametrization say $s$ with the same image $z([a, b])$ then **what can we say about the end points** of $s$? Can we say that $s(a)$ one of $z(a)$ or $z(b)$? It seems to me intuitively that this has to be the case but I am unable to prove. Assume that $s$ is also a nice parametrization from $[a, b]$.

I am interested in this question because this will have implications about integration of functions along different parametrizations of the 'same' curve (as a set).

Please help.

Comment: Any feedback on the answer? Please let me know if something is still unclear.

Comment: Thanks, it is perfect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let  $z$ and $s$ be two continuous and bijective maps from $[a, b]$ to the same set $A \subset \Bbb C$ and consider the function $f = s^{-1} \circ z$:

- $f$ is a bijective function from the interval $[a, b]$ to itself.
- $f$ is continuous (see for example [Proving the inverse of a continuous function is also continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/541082/42969)).

As a consequence, $f$ is strictly monotone (see for example [Continuous injective map is strictly monotonic](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/752073/42969)).

It follows that indeed $z$ and $s$ have the same endpoints (as you suspected).
Either $z(a) = s(a)$ and $z(b)=s(b)$ (if $f$ is increasing), or $z(a) = s(b)$ and $z(b)=s(a)$ (if $f$ is decreasing).